How to add a square card at the end of a rectangle card in Flutter
How can I do this in flutter ? Basically adding a square card at the end of a rectangle card and they have different colors. I tried making a card and adding another one to its Trailing but that was stupid

I tried making a card and adding another one to its Trailing

No need to think about trailing, that's if there's even a trailing for the card widget.
Just compose all you need as a child for the card:

Here's the code:
    Card(
      child: Container(
        height: 120,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: Container(
                height: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.red.shade300,
                child: Text('Some Text')
              )
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.blue.shade300,
                child: Center(
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 50,
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                      'https://images.pexels.com/photos/614810/pexels-photo-614810.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=600'
                    ),

                  )
                ),
              )
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
 


try this:
       Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              const Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text('Problem'),
                  Text('this is a very long description'),
                ],
              ),
              Expanded(child: Container()),
              Container(
                height: 70,
                width: 70,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    color: Colors.grey),
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.person,
                  size: 36,
                  color: Colors.black45,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),

I'm not entirely sure of your specific requirements, but I believe this approach will meet your needs.
